# Django: how to get a dictionary with a related object as key from a querydict

Tags: python, django

Lets say we have the following models: (simplified)

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Brochure(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection)

class Page(models.Model):
    brochures = models.ManyToMany(Brochure)
```

- There are 2 collections 'x' and 'y'.
- A page has a selection of brochures, not all.

Is there a way to get a dictionary of brochures like this:

```
{'x': [brochure1, brochure2], 'y': [brochure3, brochure4]}
```

only by using the many-to-many manager:

```
page_instance.brochures.all()
```

EDIT

I want to work with the brochures related to Page. Not Brochures.objects.all() or collection_instance.brochure_set. That's why I included Page.

I found defaultdict, which helps me do this:

```
collection_brochures = defaultdict(list)
for b in self.brochures.all():
    collection_brochures[b.collection.slug].append(b)
```

Actually this is the answer to my question.

I can work with this, but ideal would be a list with dicts like this:

```
[{'collection': 'x', 'brochures': [brochure1, brochure2]}, {'collection': 'y', 'brochures': [brochure3, brochure4]}]
```

Comment: Try to elaborate on your question. It looks like you want a dictionary where they keys are Collection instances and the values are a list of that collection's Brochure instances. Is that correct? I'm not sure why Page is relevant to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code snippet will do the job.

```
collection_brochures = defaultdict(list)
for b in self.brochures.all():
    collection_brochures[b.collection.slug].append(b)
result = []
for collection, brochures in collection_brochures.iteritems():
    result.append({'collection': collection, 'brochures': brochures})
```

Also you can use model instances as keys, so if you wish to see `Collection` instances instead of their slugs, you may replace third line with this one:

```
collection_brochures[b.collection].append(b)
```

This will give you following data:

```
[{'collection': collection_x, 'brochures': [brochure1, brochure2]},
 {'collection': collection_y, 'brochures': [brochure3, brochure4]}]
```